# Php code get only the current date (system date)

Tags: php, date

php code

```
<td><?php print strftime('%c'); ?></td>
```

This code is giving me the current date with the time .. But i want only the current date of the system... What ll be the code for it ??? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this:

```
<td><?php print strftime('%D'); ?></td> 
 //output will be 02/05/13 for February 5, 2013
```

OR you can use:

```
<td><?php print strftime('%F'); ?></td>
//output will be 2013-02-05 for February 5, 2013
```

For more read [tutorial here](http://php.net/strftime).

Comment: @sarmistha Miss my pleasure to help and you can also use the my code will get same result and can read the tutorial linked in my answer.

Comment: heart can u help me with this ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468908/match-the-date-from-datepicker-to-the-available-databse-day-and-show-the-result/20469448?noredirect=1#comment30589422_20469448

Comment: @sarmistha ohk I will try. but I am not able to put the answer there as the question is on hold so if you don't mind then can you come on chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42920/discussion-between-broken-heart--and-sarmistha)

Answer (score 4):

you can get the **server date**

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>
```

it will give you the system date

to get the **User system date:**

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
document.write(today);
```

Comment: Class 'Date' not found.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use strftime function only:

then please have a look at http://php.net/strftime

i think you want like this::
 **02/05/09** for February 5, 2009

Comment: i just want to add current date

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
date("Y-m-d")
```